# Temporary Re pointing of Brick work

Tags: mortar

I have some damp in a bedroom which is because the wall outside needs re-pointing.

I will do this in the summer but what can I do as a temporary fix

Comment: A bit more info on the structure would be helpful. Possibly cover the wall with a tarp or plastic to prevent rain from getting to the wall.

Comment: are  you certain that is the cause?